# mysql transfer passwords hashed with password()

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I am trying to transfer a big MySQL database which hash tables with Users and their credentials

The passwords of the users which are stored in those tables are stored with the MySQL password() method. Upon transferring them to the new machine, it seems that the hashed passwords are no longer valid.

Is there any way to transfer password() encrypted fields to the new server with them working properly? Thanks

*** EDIT ***

I was indeed facing compatibility issues. My MySQL version was generating 16-byte hash passwords, however the new version of MySQL I installed was using the new 41-byte hashing method.

However, I've found a solution,

I've set `old_passwords=1` in the my.cfg MySQL config then, the new version of mysql will use the old hashing of passwords. However, I don't recommend anyone to do this because the new hashing method of newer mysql servers is better and safer. Sadly, I cannot do this because I have more than 100 applications on the server

The best solution is provided by dlyaza above.

Comment: Did you copy the password to the new instance of the database and did you use the same function for your login purpose?

Comment: The application is the same, I just wanted to transfer everythin as-is from an old server to a new more powerful server. I copied everything (including the passowrds) and everything works fine except the passwords... example of a password is: *4ACFE3202A5FF5CF467898FC58AAB1D615029441

Comment: I've run a query ( SELECT password('test') ) to see the results on both servers, the results are:
Old server : 378b243e220ca493
New server : *94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29

Answer (score 1):

You are facing compatibility issues for MySQL password() function, please read this article in detail: 
[6.1.2.4 Password Hashing in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html)
.

In short, MySQL provides `old_password()` for compatibility when moving from old server to new server. Therefore, for new server, you could use:

`SELECT old_password('test')`

Procedure to fix this issue:

1. add new filed in the table as `password2` or any name.
2. Use old_password() for authenticating user on new server, if the password is valid, then save a copy in the field that created at step 1.
3. once you converted all user passwords, then you can use password() normally.

Comment: Yes you are right... I've found that too, is there a way to setup mysql in confugration to use the old hashing method? Because I don't know the functions and I cannot modify the applications